# How to Validate SharePoint column by Date using IF

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list, validation

I want to validate column by Type of employee.

Type of Employee: 
 - Contact
 - Full Time

I want to validate a column for "Hire Date"(Type: Date) by "Employee Type" column.

I want the date to Null/Blank/Not selectable if "Employee Type" column is Contact.
The option must be available only if the "Employee Type" column is Full Time.

I tried `=IF([Employee Type]="Contract Employee", "Null")` not worked.

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using *Javascript*.

Please try the below format.

Put it in the JS file and add this code to the List's "New/Edit" forms using "Content Editor Web Part".

---

> $(document).ready(function() {
>  decideFunc();
>
> $('select[id*="EmployeeType"]').on('change',function(e){
>
> decideFunc();
>  })
>  });
>
> > function decideFunc(){
> > if($('select[id*="EmployeeType"] option:selected').val()!="Contact")
> > {
> > hideColumn();
> > }
> > else
> > {
> > showColumn();
> > }
> > }*//decideFunc ends*
> >
> > function hideColumn(){
> > $('input[id*="HireDate"]').closest("tr").hide();
> > $('input[id*="HireDate"]').val("");//clear the value while hide
> > }*//hideColumn ends*
> >
> > function showColumn(){
> > $('input[id*="HireDate"]').closest("tr").show();
> > if(!$('input[id*="HireDate"]' ).val().trim().length){
> > $('input[id*="HireDate"]').val("");}
> >  }//showColumn ends

Answer (score 0):

did You consider using JSLink? this is a kind of Javascript attached to a column which will be 'visible' in all forms (list view, edit form, add from, display form) where the column is present.

- You can add JSLink to column Via Powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$web = Get-SPWeb "url" 
$list = $web.Lists["listName"];
$field = $list.Fields.GetField("fieldName");
$field.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/examplefile.js" 
$field.Update(true)
```

- or via c# which will be executed on feature active (very similar code to powershell)

please be aware that the JSlink may be stored under _layouts, or _catalogs or style library
like

```
~sitecollection/Style Library/JSFiles/File.js
```

other referent types are

- ~site – reference to the current SharePoint site (or “Web”)
- ~sitecollection – reference to the current SharePoint site collection (or “Site”)
- ~layouts – version specific reference to the web application Layouts folder (so it will automatically swap out /_layouts/14 or /_layouts/15 for you)
- ~sitecollectionlayouts – reference to the layouts folder in the current site collection (e.g. /sites/team/_layouts/15)
- ~sitelayouts – reference to the layouts folder in the current site (e.g. /sites/teams/subsite/_layouts/15)

then in this JSLink in on edit form You could add custom Javascript logic to make field readonly based on value from other column. The code should look like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var ctx = {};

    function init() {
        ctx.Templates = {};
        ctx.Templates.Fields = {
            'fieldName': {
                'EditForm': ReadOnly
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
    }

    function ReadOnly(ctx) {
            //console.log(ctx);
            var val = ctx.CurrentFieldValue;
            return "" + val + "";
        }

    init();

})();
```

I hope this will help :)